# How to add code for .NET MAUI controls for MacOS apps?

Tags: xcode, maui

Using VS2022 (for Mac); building a .NET MAUI for MacOS app.

How do you add code to interact with controls?

I can add controls via the XCode editor, but I don't understand how to interact with the controls via the .NET Maui API.

I was looking for a similar workflow to the Multi-Platform project type where you can edit the XAML and code behind. It's unclear to me how to do this via the MacOS project type.

Since this is in preview there are no product docs that I could find.

Comment: it doesn't sound like this is actually a MAUI app.  You need to create a Multi Platform MAUI app and then you can remove the other platforms if you only want to target Mac OS.

Comment: IMHO, Microsoft has not yet done a good job of describing how to use `.Net 6` itself on different platforms, versus using the `Maui cross-platform UI views`. **1)** If you are using `MacOS API and XCode`, until docs catch up, [OPINION] you might be better off using [Xamarin.Mac](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/). **2)** If you *do* want to use `Maui UI controls`, then you *won't* use Xcode. You would use the `MacCatalyst` support of Maui. [MacCatylst](https://developer.apple.com/mac-catalyst/) is the macos support for iOS API, plus desktop features (e.g. multiple windows).